# How to update with join query and case when condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

below query is just updating INTIME and OUTTIME and rest of case when condition is not getting calculating as per case when condition.

```
Update EmployeesAttendance 
set  EmployeesAttendance.INTIME=@INTime,
EmployeesAttendance.OUTTIME=@OUTTIME,
EmployeesAttendance.Hours= ( (DATEDIFF(Hour,OUTTIME,INTIME))),  
EmployeesAttendance.Days =(  CASE WHEN  EmployeesAttendance.Hours >= 
EmployeeDetails.Dhour THEN 1
WHEN  EmployeesAttendance.Hours = 0 THEN 0
WHEN  EmployeesAttendance.Hours >= 6 THEN 0.5 end),
EmployeesAttendance.OT=(CASE WHEN  EmployeesAttendance.Hours > 
 EmployeeDetails.Dhour then  
 EmployeesAttendance.Hours - EmployeeDetails.Dhour else 0 End),
 EmployeesAttendance.OTAmount =(CASE when EmployeeDetails.OTEntitled = 'Yes' 
 AND EmployeesAttendance .Hours >= EmployeeDetails.Dhour 
 THEN (( EmployeesAttendance.Hours - EmployeeDetails.Dhour) * 100) else 0 
 END 
 ),   
 EmployeesAttendance.Time=( 
 Convert(varchar(10),EmployeesAttendance.INTIME,108)),
 EmployeesAttendance.Late=(Case When Convert(Time, EmployeesAttendance 
.INTIME,108) > EmployeeDetails.LTime Then 1 else 0
end)    
From  EmployeeDetails 
    INNER Join EmployeesAttendance ON EmployeeDetails.EmpId = 
EmployeesAttendance.EmpID
--  Order by EmployeeDetails.EmpID asc
where EmployeesAttendance.AttIDS=@AttIDS
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to DBA.SE, could you add as much information as possible, such as the table definition, the expected result, the SQL Server version, ... . Doing that makes it easier for us, and faster for you to get the solution you want.

Comment: @RandiVertongen i have two table one is employee Details and second one is employee attendance ,in Employee attendance i am updating INTIME and OUTTIME ,then i am taking difference INTIME and OUTIME which is hours,then Calculating Day in Employee attendance from standard duty time which is defined in employee details table ...

Answer (score 0):

Try running the update like this:

I could not test because the table definitions were not provided, but generally when `updating from` this is the syntax:

```
 Update EA
    set  EA.INTIME=@INTime,
    EA.OUTTIME=@OUTTIME,
    EA.Hours= ( (DATEDIFF(Hour,OUTTIME,INTIME))),  
    EA.Days =(  CASE WHEN  EA.Hours >= 
    ED.Dhour THEN 1
    WHEN  EA.Hours = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN  EA.Hours >= 6 THEN 0.5 end),

    EA.OT=(CASE WHEN  EA.Hours > 
     ED.Dhour then  
     EA.Hours - ED.Dhour else 0 End),

     EA.OTAmount =(CASE when ED.OTEntitled = 'Yes' 
     AND EmployeesAttendance .Hours >= ED.Dhour 
     THEN (( EA.Hours - ED.Dhour) * 100) else 0 
     END ),   

     EA.Time=( 
     Convert(varchar(10),EA.INTIME,108)),
     EA.Late=(Case When Convert(Time, EmployeesAttendance 
    .INTIME,108) > ED.LTime Then 1 else 0
    end)  

    From  EmployeesAttendance EA
    INNER Join EmployeeDetail ED 
            ON ED.EmpId = EA.EmpID
    --  Order by ED.EmpID asc
    where EA.AttIDS=@AttIDS
```

from this link there is the code below, that you can take as an example:

[SQL Server: Update From Select Statement](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/update-from-select)

```
use tempdb
go

/* Creating First table */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTecBits_Table_1](
[Sl_no] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Description] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into MyTecBits_Table_1 values ('Name One','Description One')
insert into MyTecBits_Table_1 values ('Name Two','Description Two')
insert into MyTecBits_Table_1 values ('Name Three','Description Three')
insert into MyTecBits_Table_1 values ('Name Four','Description Four')

/* Creating Second table */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTecBits_Table_2](
[Sl_no] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Description] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into MyTecBits_Table_2 values ('1st Name','1st Description')
insert into MyTecBits_Table_2 values ('2nd Name','2nd Description')
insert into MyTecBits_Table_2 values ('3rd Name','3rd Description')
insert into MyTecBits_Table_2 values ('4th Name','3rd Description')

--before the update
select *
From MyTecBits_Table_2 as b Inner Join MyTecBits_Table_1 as a 
    On a.Sl_no = b.Sl_no

    --have a look at the update here
Update MyTecBits_Table_1 
Set Name = b.Name, Description = b.Description
From MyTecBits_Table_2 as b Inner Join MyTecBits_Table_1 as a 
    On a.Sl_no = b.Sl_no

--after the update
select *
From MyTecBits_Table_2 as b Inner Join MyTecBits_Table_1 as a 
    On a.Sl_no = b.Sl_no
```

[image]